# How to access html element inside form

Tags: html, angularjs

```
<form name="vesselForm" novalidate>
   <input type="text" id="owner" name="ownerEdit" required ng-blur="vesselForm.btnCC.attr('value', 'Change Customer')"/>
<input type="button" name="btnCC" value="Customer" />
</form>
```

I want to change the value of button from 'Customer' to 'Change Customer'. Tried a no. of ways:

```
vesselForm.btnCC.value='Change Customer'
this.vesselForm.btnCC.value='Change Customer'
vesselForm.btnCC.value('Change Customer')
document.btnCC.value='Change Customer'
vesselForm.btnCC.attr('value', 'Change Customer')
```

but no success. Would be thankful for any help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you provide the actual HTML/JavaScript you are currently using?

Comment: You want your input to control the name of a button, right?

Comment: yes, not exactly name but the text / value of button, using ng-blur ...

Comment: Hi, issue has been solved by using onblur in stead of ng-blur as: onblur="document.getElementById('btnCC').value='Change Customer'"

Answer (score 0):

If you are wanting to do this from some javascript that is fired by an event, then you'll need to add

`document.getelementById('btnCC').value = "Change Customer";`

HTML

```
<input blah blah onblur="document.getelementById('btnCC').value='Change Customer'" />
```

Comment: no I am not using any Javascript, I just want to change the value here in this html file using ng-blur

Comment: thanks for your response, but try to understand, I dont want to use javascript. this should be possible to access an element within html

Comment: Glad you got it figured out using the small javascript line instead of using the function I posted originally. I edited my answer to match exactly what you did. Could you please mark this post as the answer so the question will show that it has been resolved? Thanks & happy coding!